# Excel VBA - Remove specific Conditional Formatting Rules

Tags: excel, vba

One of the client's spreadsheets (with 1 sheet) contains **2** Conditional Formatting rules by default and I usually add several new rules for my own convenience.

I want to remove all the new rules that I've created but keep the client ones.

#### Script:

```
Sub Remove_New_Formatting()

    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Count
            .FormatConditions.Item(i).Delete
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

#### Result:

When I run the script, only several rules are being removed and then I get **'Subscript out of range'** error.

I can't identify what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `For i = ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Count To 3 Step -1`. Loop backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deleting the most natural way to loop is backwards

```
Sub Remove_New_Formatting()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions
        For i = .Count To 3 Step -1
            .Item(i).Delete
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```